# Can we use big data concept in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, bigdata

As Big Data term used widely to manage huge data, I want to give a try to build a small application with Big Data to understand structure and how I can start with ASP.NET technology?

Is it possible?

Comment: No. This is not possible. Microsoft restricts ASP.NET to only working on little data. Big data just won't work.

Comment: [Obligitory](https://d262ilb51hltx0.cloudfront.net/max/800/1*cLk_niE2JlJcHwWU0IFc8Q.png)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt147240.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Big data" is a marketing term for "highly scalable large load computing". So can you use ASP.NET for highly scalable large load computing...

Yes, and [here is how](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.08.scaling.aspx) (Scaling Strategies for ASP.NET Applications).

Comment: Note this answer was written pre ASP.Net Core, you can still do "big data" but the advice in the article may not the correct advice for core in it.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Scott's answer, apart from ASP.NET being capable of scaling to high loads with effective strategies, .NET ecosystem also provides [HDInsight](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-get-started/) in Azure, which implements MapReduce programming model to query over large clusters of Data.

Azure HDInsight could closely be related to the marketing buzzword of 'Hadoop','Big Data' etc.